# Why does the order topology of some set have to contain **all** subsets on that set in the form of [a_0, b) and (a, b_0]?

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently reading Munkres' topology book, and when he defines the order topology on a set, he states that the order topology contains **all** subsets of that set in the form [a_0, b) and (a, b_0], along with all sets (a, b), where a_0 and b_0 are the smallest and largest elements in that set respectively. Why is it that we need to define all of those sets, as opposed to just one for each? For example, if I had [a_0, c) and (b, d) within my basis, and open sets in a topology are simply unions of basis elements, I can construct the subset [a_0, d) by taking the union of those two elements, so why is it necessary that I include [a_0, d) in my basis?

Comment: If $d\lt c$ then $[a_0,c)\cup(b,d)=[a_0,c)\ne[a_0,d)$.

Comment: @bof I'm saying that c < d

Comment: @bof But what if c < d?

Comment: If $[a_0,c)$ is the one interval with left endpoint $a_0$ that you put in your base, and if $a_0\lt d\lt c$, why do you need to add $[a_0,d)$ to your base? Well, if you want $[a_0,d)$ to be an open set, then you need to add $[a_0,d)$ (or else $[a_0,e)$ for some $e\lt d$) to your base, **if you want $[a,d)$ to be an open set,** as Munkres does. If **you** want a topology where $[a_0,d)$ is **not** an open set, well and good, but then it's not **the order topology** as that term is generally understood.

Comment: Yes, but is it necessary to contain [a0,d) within the base if I can simply construct it from a union of basis elements (which would make it an open set)?

Comment: Couldn't [a0,d) be in the topology without being in the basis?

Comment: Of course, if you just want a **base** for the order topology, you wouldn't necessarily have to include **all** sets of the form $[a_0,c)$. For example, if you're ordered set is $[0,1]$, instead of taking **all** intervals $[0,c)$ for **all** $c\in(0,1)$, it would be enough to take the intervals $[0,0.1),\ [0,0.001),\ [0,0.0001),\dots$. I guess Munkres figured it would be simpler to just take them all. Particularly since he's defining the order topology for a general ordered set, not just $[0,1]$.

Comment: Munkres is not trying to define the **smallest** base for the order topology, just one good one. If you want the **smallest** base, that's another question. As a matter of fact, in nontrivial cases (say if the ordered set is $[0,1]$), **there is no smallest base** — for any base, there is a proper subset which is still a base.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are saying. Just to clarify, for the example that you presented with the ordered set [0, 1], could I, for example, eliminate [0, 0.1) as a basis element, since it can be expressed as the union of say, [0, 0.001) and another open interval (a, 0.1) with a < 0.001?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it that you are only complaining about the intervals $[a_0,b)$ and $(b,b_0]$, and you are apparently O.K. with using all the intervals $(a,b)$? After all, in most cases, $(a,b)$ can be written as the union of two smaller intervals.

Comment: I'm not really sure, hadn't even thought of that until now.

Comment: But would the statement that I outlined in my previous comment be possible (just for my conceptual understanding)?

Comment: Sure, $[0,0.001)=[0,0.0001)\cup(0.00001,0.001)$.

Comment: Ok great, thank you for all your help.

Comment: To sum up: (a) You noticed that the base for the order topology defined in your textbook is not a minimal base; you can throw out some set and still have a base for the same topology. Good observation. (b) You feel that this is a problem. No, it isn't. Nobody claimed that it was minimal, nobody needs it to be minimal. In most interesting topologies there is **no minimal base** to be found. An example where there is a minimal base is the discrete topology; the minimal base consists of all the one-element sets.

Comment: Exactly, thank you for clarifying things

Answer (score 0):

The order topology on $(X,<)$ is the smallest topology such that all sets 
of the form $L(x) = \{y \in X: y < x\}$, where $x \in X$ (the left sets) and all sets of the form $R(x) = \{y \in X: y > x\}$ where $x \in X$ (the right sets) are both open.

All these sets together form a so-called subbase for the order topology.

The base generated by the subbase is the set of all finite intersections of sets from the subbase (including intersections of one set, which ensures all subbase elements are also in the base).

As $L(x_1) \cap L(x_2) = L(\min(x_1,x_2))$ and $R(x_1)\cap R(x_2) = R(\max(x_1,x_2))$, we only get new base elements by intersecting a set of the form $L(x_1)$ and one of the form $R(x_2)$, which gives us open intervals $(x_2,x_1)$ with endpoints in $X$. These are truly new types of open sets.

If $X$ has a minimum $m$, then clearly $L(x) = [m,x)$, and so these sets, being in the generating subbase are in the base too. Munkres wants to be explicit in including these in the form $[m,x)$, instead of $L(x)$. Similar considerations hold if $X$ has a maximum $M$ and then $R(x) = (x,M]$. Munkres wants to be explicit in the fact that basic neighbourhoods of $m$ and $M$ (if they exist) look a bit different from the basic neighbourhoods of other points, that are open intervals with endpoints on both sides.

The subbase and resulting base are not meant to be minimal, just convenient.
E.g. for $\mathbb{R}$ we can limit ourselves to intervals and left/right sets (aka open segments) with endpoints in $\mathbb{Q}$, because of the order density of the rationals. In $[0,1]$ we can for basic neighbourhoods of $0$ suffice with sets $[0,\frac{1}{n})$, instead of all $[0,x)$ etc. But we want to describe the order topology in full generality, so in that we need to include the full base, not some thinned out subset of it.